# Is there a way to get back to the map once off it in Mine craft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I find myself off the edge of the map and trying to get back to my settlment. Is there a way to find out where I am or to transport back?

Comment: Are you saying that you have the item named map, and it is centered on your settlement?

Comment: If the above is the case, you literally just walk to where your settlement was and your arrow will reappear on the map.

Comment: @Guy He is off the map.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your map, you have an indicator:

[image: Indicator on map]

When you create a map **it will always be north facing** - that is to say, the top edge of the map will be north. When on this map, the arrow will always float around in the direction that you are currently facing.

When you leave the edge of the map, you will get a square indicator:

[image: Indicator off map]

This merely indicates the direction you have disappeared off the map. So to get back *onto* the map, head in the opposite direction:

- If off the *top* of the map: Head *south*
- If off the *left* of the map: Head *east*
- If off the *bottom* of the map: Head *north*
- If off the *right* of the map: Head *west*

You can determine which way you are currently facing by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>

[image: F3 coordinate info]

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have an in-game map, or the coordinates, the short answer is no. I would recommend downloading a map mod where you can waypoint your home/s, and never lose them again :)